# Why is /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh /run.sh always running?

Tags: process, docker, background-process

From the moment I turn on my laptop (Ubuntu) and run `htop` to observe running processes, there are always these four that seem to spawn from the following command: `/bin/bash /entrypoint.sh /run.sh` [image: screenshot of htop output]

I am trying to understand what these processes are and what they are responsible for. When I try to kill them using `kill -9 <pid>`, they immediately respawn. I also can't find any file named `/entrypoint.sh` or `/run.sh`. From doing some googling online, I can tell that these processes might be related to docker, but I don't really know how to continue investigating given that information.

Any ideas on:

1. Why do these processes spawn every time I boot my laptop?
2. What are they doing?
3. Should I kill them and how?

Edit: some more information:

1. `sudo docker ps` returns no active containers
2. `sudo docker ps --all` returns no containers either
3. `sudo docker ps --last 10` returns no containers, thus I believe my docker installation is fresh.

Comment: Do you have docker installed? Tried `docker ps`?

Comment: @tkausl yes, `docker ps` returns no active containers.

Comment: Follow the chain of parents, there might be something interesting.

Comment: The immediate parent process is always `containerd-shim`. The parent process always spawns a bunch of other child processes that are also `containerd-shim`. Each `/entrypoint.sh` spawns either `sed` or `sleep`. There is more: there is a fifth process that appeared after I took the screenshot, this one is just `/bin/bash /run.sh`. It's parent is also `containerd-shim`, but unlike `/entrypoint.sh`, `/run.sh` spawns around 50 child processes, all are `java`. What do you make of this?

Edit: typo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After following the chain of parents as @tkausl advised, I noticed that all parent processes were `containerd-shim`. Inspecting the output of `pstree -p`, I noticed many other top-level processes that were either `containerd-shim`, `containerd` or `dockerd`. Each of these would respawn if I tried to kill them. As I did not actively use docker or containerd (to the best of my knowledge), I uninstalled both of them, which made all of these processes go away.I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/5708) GitHub issue complaining about undying `containerd-shim` processes, which might be related.